# Map over generic collection in Java 11

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-11

I've been trying to find a way to write a generic function -- possibly not using generics -- to map over a collection.

Let's say I have a function A to B, I'd like to write a function that takes a `Collection<A>` and returns a `Collection<B>`. NOTE that A and B are not generics, just a way to express a general pattern.

What I have so far is

```
public static Collection<Point> points2dToPoints(Collection<Point2D> points) {
    return points.stream()
            .map(Utils::point2dToPoint)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> points));

}
```

However, I get a type error in the `.collect`, because obviously I want the new collection to be `Collection<Point>` but I'm not sure how to get a Supplier for that?

Edit: I would like to be able to use this function in a generic way: if I pass it a Set I get a Set in return, but if I pass it a List I get a list in return. is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Just use `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what if I don't know if it's a list? I would like to be able to pass it a Set, and get a Set in return, but when I pass it a List I get a List

Comment: that is an important detail to specify.  It is _impossible_ to solve that problem in general: you can't guarantee that the kind of collection you get in can even be created by other code at all.  All you can do is attempt to catch common cases: `if (points instanceof Set) { // use toSet... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to not overcomplicate, and simply do:

```
public static Collection<Point> points2dToPoints(Collection<Point2D> points) {
    return points.stream()
            .map(Utils::point2dToPoint)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

returning a concrete implement of interface `Collection` (*e.g.,* `Collectors.toList()`) while hiding from the outside the implementation details, (*i.e.,* having `Collection` in the method signature).

You can, however, make your method more generic by passing to it -- as `Supplier` -- which concrete implementation of the interface `Collection` you want it to return, namely

```
 public static Collection<Point> points2dToPoints(Collection<Point2D> points, Supplier<Collection<Point>> aNew) {
        return points.stream()
                .map(Utils::point2dToPoint)
                .collect(toCollection(aNew));
```

In this way you can pass the concrete `Collection` implementation that will be returned, for example:

```
points2dToPoints(.., ArrayList::new);
points2dToPoints(.., TreeSet::new);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the statement `Collectors.toCollection(() -> points)` with `Collectors.toList()`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Car {
    String name;

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

class Book {
    Car car;

    public Book(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        Collection<Car> list = points2dToPoints(
                List.of(new Book(new Car("Toyota")), new Book(new Car("Ford")), new Book(new Car("Suzuki"))));

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static Collection<Car> points2dToPoints(Collection<Book> points) {
        return points.stream().map(Book::getCar).collect(Collectors.toList());    
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Car [name=Toyota]
Car [name=Ford]
Car [name=Suzuki]
```